# Guardar valor de um ng-repeat e utilizar em outro

Tags: angularjs

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Primeiro eu realizo uma busca e preencho meu primeiro select com ng-repeat. Até ai tudo bem, porém eu realizo outro busca para um segundo select que depende dessa minha primeira busca. Como eu faço para pegar o valor desse primeiro ng-repeat?

Segue meus códigos

```
        <div ng-controller="ctrSecretariaPrograma">
      <label>Programa:<b><span style="color: red;">*</span></b></label></br>
      <select required ng-model="lista_programa_pos.model" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Selecione o Programa</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in lista_programa_pos.availableOptions" value="{{option.cod_programa}}">{{option.nome_programa}}</option>
      </select>

      <label></br>Curso:<b><span style="color: red;">*</span></b></label></br>
      <select required ng-model="lista_curso.model" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Selecione o Curso</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in lista_curso.availableOptions" value="{{option.cod_curso}}">{{option.nome_curso}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Preciso do valor do primeiro select para realizar a busca no segundo, segue meu código js

```
      $scope.lista_programa_pos = {
    model: null,
    availableOptions: null
  };

  $scope.lista_curso = {
    model: null,
    availableOptions: null
  };

  var getProgramaPos = function () {
    $http.get("getProgramaPos").then(function (resposta) {
        $scope.lista_programa_pos.availableOptions = resposta.data;
    });

  }; getProgramaPos();


  var getCurso = function(option.cod_programa){
    var data = {
      cod_programa: option.cod_programa
    };

    $http.get("getCurso", data).then(function(resposta){
      $scope.lista_curso.availableOptions = resposta.data;
    });

  }; getCurso(option.cod_programa);
```

Não sei se estou chamando certa função, pois uma depende da outra e também não sei como pegar esse valor na parte getCurso(option.cod_programa), aonde seria o código que guardo no meu primeiro ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVIDO!

Utilizei o ng-change para chamar minha função getCurso() meu código alterado ficou assim:

```
          <select required ng-model="lista_programa_pos.model" class="form-control" ng-change="getCurso(lista_programa_pos.model);">
            <option value="">Selecione o Programa</option>
            <option ng-repeat="option in lista_programa_pos.availableOptions" value="{{option.cod_programa}}">{{option.nome_programa}}</option>
          </select>
```

Meu arquivo js:

```
$scope.getCurso = function(cod_programa){

console.log(cod_programa);
var data = {
  cod_programa: cod_programa
};

$http.post("getCurso", data).then(function(resposta){


     $scope.lista_curso.availableOptions = resposta.data;
    });

  };
```

Retirando o var e adicionando $scope e retirando a chamada de função automatica